# TreeDataGridView with virtual mode

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview

I'm developing a variant of DGV that is capable of showing hierarchical data like TreeView. The tricky bit is that both the root row list and the child row lists need to support huge collections so I want them to be virtual. The best way I've thought of to make this work is overriding the underlying CellValueNeeded with one which has a list of row indexes instead of a single row index. So a row index list like {42,123,45} would mean "the 46th child row of the 124th child row of the 43rd root row".

Efficiently mapping from the flat row index to the hierarchical list (and vice versa) for potentially millions of rows will require some clever data structures. Has anybody already done this and can provide some tips?