# What is the most space efficient way to store an N-ary tree while preserving hierarchy traversal?

Tags: c#, optimization, data-structures, tree

I read [this paper](http://www.mcs.le.ac.uk/~rraman/papers/own/geary-etal-talg-2006.pdf).

But I'd love to avoid a ton of research to solve this problem if someone has already done it. I need this space efficient tree for a reasonably (conceptually) simple GUI control: [TreeDataGridView with virtual mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193526/treedatagridview-with-virtual-mode)

An example tree might look like:

```
(RowIndexHierarchy),ColumnIndex
(0),0                          
  (0,0),0                      
    (0,0,0),0                  
      (0,0,0,0),0              
        (0,0,0,0,0),0          
      (0,0,0,1),0              
      (0,0,0,2),0              
    (0,0,1),0                  
    (0,0,2),0                  
      (0,0,2,0),0              
      (0,0,2,1),0              
      (0,0,2,2),0              
  (0,1),0                      
  (0,2),0                      
    (0,2,0),0                  
      (0,2,0,0),0              
      (0,2,0,1),0              
      (0,2,0,2),0              
    (0,2,1),0                  
    (0,2,2),0                  
    (0,2,2,0),0                
      (0,2,2,1),0              
      (0,2,2,2),0              
(1),0
```

I need operations like "find flat row index from row hierarchy" and "find row hierarchy from flat row index". Also, to support expand/collapse, I need "find next node with the same or less depth".

Comment: @Johan: Tree data structures are happily language-agnostic. I'm fine to port from one language to the GUI language (C#).

Comment: What is `ColumnIndex` and why is always 0? And what is “flat row index”?

Comment: @svick: The DataGridView is a basic table with row index and column index for each cell. My TreeDataGridView subclass replaces the flat row index with a hierarchical one but it still has to map back and forth. The above example is just showing the row/column indexes for the first column of a possible tree.

Comment: So, for example, flat row index for `(0,0,2,1)` would be 10?

Answer (score 0):

For read-only tree you can store sorted array of nodes by its parent index.

```
0 a
1 (a/)b
1 (a/)c
2 (a/b/)d
2 (a/b/)e
2 (a/b/)f
3 (a/c/)c
```

Each time you'll need to find child nodes you can use binary search to find upper and lower boundaries of nodes range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am following your needs exactly, but we access a database that has a tree-view UI. The tree runs from

Top Level (the user's company);
Direct Client Company;
Office Location;
Employee;
Indirect Client Company;
Proposal;
Specific Vendor Bid;
Detail Financials (invoices, adjustments, etc)

As we have thousands of direct clients and the tree branches pretty heavily at each tier, so we don't load the entire data-set at any time. Instead we only load Type, Guid, DisplayName and some administrative data for each child and load a "details" pane for the currently focused item. Unexplored paths through the tree simply don't exist in memory. To avoid loading the full lists of names, we have "rolodex" level that just divides the dataset into batches of 100 records or less. (So "Z" stands alone, but "Sa-St" subdivides S). These auto-insert when a subset grows beyond the 100 record threshold.

Periodically (when the system is idle) we check the loaded count and if it exceeds a threshold we drop the least recently used nodes until we are below the threshold.

The actual data access is done when the user navigates: we access the database and refresh the subset they are navigating through. We do have the advantage that Type determines the table to query (both for that level and the children) and thus we can keep the individual record types indexed and accessible.

This has given the user the ability to navigate through the data in any way they want, while keeping the in-memory retained data minimized. Of course we off standard search modes and a menu of "recently used history" (for each type) as well, but often the work they do requires moving up and down a narrow chain of nodes, so the tree view keeps it all in front of them while working with a given client and the subset.

With that background, I become curious as to the nature of data that would have such undifferentiated levels that such a tier by tier data store wouldn't be appropriate. The advantage that tier by tier storage has is that all I need is the current node's Guid and I can search the child table on that as the foreign key (which is indexed, so quick to return the subset).

I guess this amounts to "unasking the question", but it seems that most tree structures have distinct data at each level, so it would seem far easier to work with something established (like a table query on an indexed field, which keeps the whole affair out of memory in the first place) than making a custom structure.

For example, I have never asked for the "next node at the current level" except within a given parent (because leaving a given parent takes me to another context). But within a parent I already have the children and their order.

Perhaps it is because of the space I'm in, but I find a tree control that knows how to bind to different tables based on parent->child relationships of tables more useful, which is why I wrote one. I also find lazy loading of data and aggressive dismissal of data keep the memory footprint minimized. Finally I find the programming model incredibly simple: just create a new "treenode" subclass for any table I want to access and make the treenode responsible for loading their children.

(Clarifying, due to question below:)

In my implementation each TreeNode is actually a SpecificTreeNode, derived from BaseNode, which in turn is derived from TreeNode. Being inherited from TreeNode, they can be used directly by the tree, but because they have overrides of the BaseNode properties such as LoadChildren and display properties, the display and retrieval any given set of data is implied by the type of node (and the Guid that the item represents).

This means that as the user navigates the tree, the SpecificTreeNode generates the required ORM query on the fly. For performance, child tables have any parent IDs as indexes, so navigating down the tree (even by multiple layers, if using a SpecificTreeNode that does rollups) is just a quick index lookup.

In this way, I keep very little of the data in memory at any time, pulling only what we need from the database. Likewise, queries against the tree are converted to ORM queries against our database, pulling only the results and limiting the amount any query can pull (if you are using a Tree UI and you pull over 100 records at once, the UI isn't really the optimal place for whatever you are doing).

When your dataset is hundreds of GB in size, it seems the only reasonable recourse. The advantage I feel this has is that the Tree itself has no idea that different levels and paths render and query differently... it just asks the BaseNode (from its perspective) to do something, and the overrides on SpecificTreeNode actually do the lifting. Thus, the "data structure" is simply the way the tree works already combined with data queries on my tables and views.

(End of clarification.)

Meanwhile all the tree controls on the market seem to miss that and go with something far more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough non-answer. :) Actually it's a great answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193526/treedatagridview-with-virtual-mode . My data is backed by a database, but the queries aggregate over many tables. To work with your tables, my columns shown for the Employee rows might be "# Proposals, Avg. Bid". And I need to show them in the table, not on selection. I also want the user to be able to change the tree hierarchy. In your case, I might want to take "Office Location" out of the hierarchy and just show all employees directly under the client company.

Comment: Yes, I didn't go into details, but we don't query the tables directly, but views for each tier. Those views pull up things like # Proposals and such on their behalf (sometimes using lookaside tables updated via triggers for complex computed values for performance). Likewise, if a user doesn't want a level of the tree, they simply use a different inherited treenode that populates children at the appropriate level, skipping any desired levels. Really, that was the key to my method: treenodes that know how to drill down intelligently.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "use a different inherited treenode". And when you say "user" do you mean a user interacting with the control or a developer coding with the control?

Comment: Updated the tail end of the response to clarify. In a way, both the developer and user "use a different inherited treenode". The user doesn't know that is how the ORM query is built or that the data was loaded via this mechanism, but they *use* it every time they drill down on a given record type. Meanwhile the developer can just create a new inherited BaseNode class for new data (such as when we added documents and invoices to the tree) or a new rollup. The key is that the node itself knows how make the appropriate query and populate children... the Tree itself just asks the Nodes to update.

Answer (score 0):

The most space-efficient way to store a balanced N-ary tree is in an array... zero space-overhead!  And actually very efficient to traverse ... just some simple math required to compute your parent index from your index... or your N children's indices from your index.

To find some code for this, look up heapsort... the heap structure (nothing to do with memory heap) is a balanced binary tree... and most people implement it in an array.  Although it is binary, the same thing can be done for N-ary.

If your N-ary tree is not kept balanced, but tends to be fairly dense, then the array implementation will still be more space-efficient than most... the empty nodes being the only space overhead.  However, if your trees are ever highly imbalanced, then the array implementation can be very space-inefficient.